# Split string using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to split`${SOMENAME} (${THISNAME}) ${THESENAME}`
I just need to extract the words SOMENAME THISNAME and THESENAME from the above string. Is it possible?

Comment: Have you tried using regex?

Comment: You could use `/\${[^}]+}/`... so `string.match(/\${[^}]+}/g)` would output: `["${SOMENAME}", "${THISNAME}", "${THESENAME}"]`.

Comment: Yes, it's possible...

Comment: @JoshCrozier You don't need to backslash the curly braces, they have no meaning in js regex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass in a regular expression separator as part of the `.split()` function.

```js
var string = "${SOMENAME} (${THISNAME}) ${THESENAME}";
var re = /\W+/;
var arr = string.split(re);
document.write(arr);
```

Take a look at [String.prototype.split](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

If you only need extract the words, this could be a simple solution:

```
var s = "${SOMENAME} (${THISNAME}) ${THESENAME}";

var words = s.match(/([A-Z])\w+/g);
```